# How to refer to an object inside a function in R?

Tags: r, function, object, dataframe, eval

How can I refer to my dataframe inside a function when building the dataframe name from several strings?

```
a <- c(1:6)
b <- c("05/12/2012 05:00","05/12/2012 06:00","06/12/2012 05:00",
   "06/12/2012 06:00", "07/12/2012 09:00","07/12/2012 07:00")
c <-c("0","0","0","1","1","1")
d <-c("12", "12", "13", "15", "16", "17") 
dataframenumber4 <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to select a value from my dataframe.

```
dataframenumber4[1,4] 

[1] 12
```

But I also want to build a function as I have multiple dataframes I want to select from:

```
selectvalue <- function(dataframe, number){
paste0(dataframe,number)[1,4]
}

selectvalue("dataframe", "number4") 

[1] NA NA NA
```

I gather this isn't right because R isn't recognizing my little string as an object name. So I tried to fix it:

```
 selectvalue <- function(dataframe, number){
eval(paste0(dataframe,number))[1,4]
}

selectvalue("dataframe", "number4")
```

Returns "Error in eval(paste0(dataframe,number, quote = FALSE))[1,4]: incorrect number of dimensions"

I've tried multiple things inside my function but I can't get R to recognize that I'm trying to give it my dataframe. How can I fix this?

Comment: The more R-friendly way will be to put those data frames in a list (`dfs <- list(dataframe1, dataframe2)` and then access using `dfs[[i]]`.

Comment: @Aaron has correctly pointed out. Its always better to creating a list of data frames and access them using `[[` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get` function to access objects by their name. The name of the data.frame is prepared using `paste0(dataframe,number)` and then you can call `get` with that name to access dataframe. Hence your function can be written as:

```
selectvalue <- function(dataframe, number){
  get(paste0(dataframe,number))[1,4]

}

selectvalue("dataframenumber",4)
[1] "12"
```

The above function works per OP's expectation but I should suggest few improvement in that function:

1. Name of the dataframe can be passed by caller directly. No need to prepare name of dataframe within function.
2. The row & column numbers are hard-coded in function. That can be passed by caller.

Hence, function can be re-written and called as:

```
selectvalue <- function(dataframe, rownum, colnum){
  get(dataframe)[rownum,colnum]

}

selectvalue(paste0("dataframenumber",4), 1 ,4)
#[1] "12"
selectvalue(paste0("dataframenumber",4), 2 ,2)
#[1] "05/12/2012 06:00"
```

Comment: This is correct, thanks! But I think my code has confusing variables so what I'm actually trying to do is: get(paste0(dataframe,number))[1,4]

selectvalue("dataframe","number4") in which the [1,4] is specified in the function; I'm "getting" the dataframe name, not the position.

Does that make sense?

regardless, it's the right answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DrHeadland I have given some more idea about re-writing your function. The basic point is about using `get` and you can put on business logic per your need.

Comment: This is neat, thanks for the advice. I hardcoded the [1,4] simply because it was the smallest code I could reproduce the errors with.